# How to delete nodes from a binary tree alongwith node in its subtree and count number of nodes left?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

A binary tree is implemented using an Array. The first element is the root node and others are children. There are N number of elements in the tree. N is taken as input from the user.

How to delete a node from it?

SUCH THAT, when deleted, all nodes in its subtree must also be deleted.

THEN, how to count number of elements left? Can I use a for loop to do so?

I have written this much code as a part of the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N, A[100], X, left, index;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    cin >> X;
    left = N;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (A[i] == X)
            index = i;
    if(index == 0)
        left = 0;
    cout << left;
}
```

The if statement for index == 0 prints 0 nodes left as the root node is also deleted. But I have no idea to find the number left if the node to be deleted is at index more than 0.

Comment: How are the elements arranged in the array? If N=15 and A[0] corresponds to the root node, what corresponds to the root node's right child? Is it A[2], or A[8], or what?

Comment: A[2] is the right node. A[1} is left to it.

Comment: `left` is always either `N` or `0` is that actually what you needed?

Comment: Yes. That is what I need.

Comment: All right, break the problem into pieces. As you iterate through the array, do you see how to keep track of the depth in the tree? If you find A[j] at depth d, do you know where that node's children are in the array (if they exist)? Do you know how to delete a single node? Solve easy problems first, then hard ones.

Comment: Yes. I know what you meant.